# How can I make the BLE communication is encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I made a smartphone app and ble service with Bluez 5.28.
the communication between them works very well.
but i'd like to crack the communication and i've tried to do with Ubertooth one and crackle.
At first, I started ubertooth and then connect to ble service with smartphone. after capturing, i tried to crack (decrypt) with crackle but crackle said:
"Unable to crack due to he following error:
  Missing both Mrand and Srand

Did not decrypt any packets, not writing a new pcap..."

In conclusion, the connection between smartphone and ble service was not encrypted. I found out that ble service flag about encryption is true, but I don't know about smartphone. I've thought android and ble support encryption automatically. 
How can I make connections between two devices encrypted?
Should I set anything in android app or ble service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pair the devices. Either go into Android's Bluetooth system settings to pair the devices, or do it programmatically using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond(). Or you can send a Security Request packet from the peripheral. When pairing is done, all further connections will be encrypted.

Note that unless you use the latest Android and your peripheral supports the new Secure Connections pairing method, you will be able to sniff all subsequent traffic if the pairing process itself was sniffed. If you didn't sniff the initial pairing, you can't decrypt the rest.